# Limitation of not being able to use variable(defined in scenario) for afterScenario

Tags: karate

I have a use case where i have to delete entries from DB in afterScenario. But i have to take decision during runtime which entries to be deleted based on one variable(id) under my scenarios.

How do i pass this in my afterScnarios JS funtion, below function doesn't seem to work:

```
* configure afterScenario =
    """
    function(id) {
    var rowDeleted = db.deleteByMid(id);
    karate.log(id + ' id delete after scenarios: ' + karate.scenario.name);
    }
    """
```

my feature file:

```
Feature
  Scenario:
     * def id = '1234'

  Scenario:
     * def id = '4566'
```

But i am getting id as null in afterScenario block:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `karate.get('id')` to get the value. Else it may be a bug in Karate, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks I will try that and update here. Till then can you please tell if two scenarios running in parallel, afterscenario block should receive their scenario specific 'id'. I just want to understand that it should not mess up with each other's value in afterScenario

Comment: @Yash it should work, else it may be a bug

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks, karate.get('id') is working fine. 
For someone who might land up here, i want to clarify it's not a bug, karate.get('id') works fine